# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have devise and a users controller for the show action of the user model.
The routes are setup like this;

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :docs

  resources :documents, only: [:new, :create, :index]

  #get 'users/show'

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:show]

  #resources :users do
    resources :personal_accounts,path: "user_account", only: [:show] do
      resources :deposits, only: [:new, :show, :create, :index]
      resources :withdraws, only: [:new, :show, :create, :index]
    end
    resources :businesses do
      resources :business_accounts, path: "business_account", only: [:show] do
        resources :business_withdraws, only: [:new, :show, :create, :index]
        resources :business_deposits, only: [:new, :show, :create, :index]
      end
    end
  #end

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root :to => 'dashboard#index'
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root :to => 'devise/registrations#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1, defaults: {format: :json}   do
     resources :payments
     resources :withdraws
     resources :balances
    end
  end
end
```

However the route `http://localhost:3000/users/1` works just fine but the route `http://localhost:3000/documents/new` does not work and throws he error **No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]**

Trace

```
Started GET "/documents/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-11 14:35:22 +0300
Processing by DocumentsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered documents/_form.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered documents/new.erb within layouts/application (2.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 63ms

ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]:
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:217:in `raise_generation_error'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:190:in `optimized_helper'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:176:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
   () Users/macbook/Desktop/projects/sentenow/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:106:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1472684571148157706_70110268755560'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:67:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
   () Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
   () Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
   () Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
   () Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'



Started POST "/__better_errors/70110284044440/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-11 14:35:22 +0300
```

Any idea where this totally unrelated error arises from?
Thank you

Comment: show the stack trace

Comment: Show 106th line of your `layouts/application.html.erb` file.

Comment: I guess you try to generate route to `users#show`, but you don't provide valid `User` instance.

Comment: show `documents#new`

Comment: Look at all the relationships in the models. Document and user appear linked at the model level.

Comment: The error was on line 106 and i changed it from `<%= user_path(@current_user) %>` to `<%= user_path(current_user) %>`